Use MLKit Barcode scanner from a module other the app module
This is a confusing problem, I've tried to use ML-kits barcode scanner to detect QR codes, if I place the dependency  implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0' in the app level Build.gradle the reader works fine. If i ty to add that in my module level build.gradle then the application crashes by citing com.google.android.gms.common.api.optionalmoduleapi class is not found. What may the issue?
I've tried adding the dependency as api from the app module, this works but I cannot do that because it'll use more space. This app also has an instant app. so the total size of the app cannot exceed 15MB as per the documentation.

Can you please [edit] your post and add the content of both gradle files as text?
